# pivot_table: pandas - how to transform pivot output for data frame and access columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'experiment_name': ['exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1'], 
'variant': ['A', 'B', 'A','B','A','B'],'sessions_with_orders':[1,2,6,0,23,12],
'total_sessions':[10,23,56,22,89,12]}
```

`Create DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)    

final_pivot=(df.pivot_table(index='variant',columns='experiment_name',values=['total_sessions','sessions_with_orders'],aggfunc=np.sum)
.assign(ratio=lambda d: d['sessions_with_orders']/d['total_sessions']) )
```

`final_pivot_reset=final_pivot.reset_index()` ##this makes an accessible data frame using .iloc

```
type(final_pivot_reset)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I don't think `final_pivot.reset_index()` is doing correct thing?

Further, I have challenge in accessing column/names from the reset output. When I look at the column names they are hierarchal (default output from `pivot_table`).

```
final_pivot_reset.columns

MultiIndex([(             'variant',     ''),
            ('sessions_with_orders', 'exp1'),
            (      'total_sessions', 'exp1'),
            (               'ratio',     '')],
           names=[None, 'experiment_name'])
```

For example, I would like to access `final_pivot_reset.ratio` how do I achieve it?

I had created a post on how to create custom column on the fly for pivot_table [pandas - pivot || create custom column for ratio/percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71969146/2740831)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten `MultiIndex` after `pivot_table` with separator `_`, so change columns names for `ratio`. Last if need convert `index` to column `variant` add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
final_pivot=df.pivot_table(index='variant',
                           columns='experiment_name',
                           values=['total_sessions','sessions_with_orders'],
                           aggfunc=np.sum)
final_pivot.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in final_pivot.columns] 
final_pivot = (final_pivot.assign(ratio=lambda d: d['sessions_with_orders_exp1']/d['total_sessions_exp1'])
                          .reset_index())
print (final_pivot)
  variant  sessions_with_orders_exp1  total_sessions_exp1     ratio
0       A                         30                  155  0.193548
1       B                         14                   57  0.245614
```

Comment: Thank you. `[f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in final_pivot.columns]` I think this flattens the multi index? However, it adds `exp1` as a suffix.

Comment: @DeathMetal - yes, because `b` is `exp1` or empty string for secon dlevel of MultiIndex